# Ruby 1.9 regex as a hash key

Tags: ruby, regex, hash

I am trying this example  `myhash = {/(\d+)/ => "hello"}` with ***ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25) [i386-mingw32]***.
It doesn't work as expected (edit: as it turned out it shouldn't work as I was expecting):

```
irb(main):004:0> myhash = {/(\d+)/ => "hello"}
=> {/(\d+)/=>"Hello"}
irb(main):005:0> myhash[2222]
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> myhash["2222"]
=> nil
```

In [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/dhuCc7Wvew) which is on ruby1.8.7 the [regex](http://www.rubular.com/r/dhuCc7Wvew) works.
What am I missing?

Comment: @gnab - well spotted. but unfortunately that's not the problem

Comment: I think you have to iterate the hash and do a normal match. It wont be fast tho.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Seems kind of strange to use a regexp as the key value of a hash.

Comment: @Jonas - it seems like I was just over complicating an easy task.

Comment: http://rubyworks.github.io/hashery/ specifically http://rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/hashery/master/Hashery/FuzzyHash

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will not work without some extra code, as it is you are comparing a Regexp object with either an Integer or a String object. They won't be value equal, nor identity equal. They would match but that requires changes to the Hash class code.

```
irb(main):001:0> /(\d+)/.class
=> Regexp
irb(main):002:0> 2222.class
=> Fixnum
irb(main):003:0> '2222'.class
=> String
irb(main):004:0> /(\d+)/==2222
=> false
irb(main):007:0> /(\d+)/=='2222'
=> false
irb(main):009:0> /(\d+)/.equal?'2222'
=> false
irb(main):010:0> /(\d+)/.equal?2222
=> false
```

you would have to iterate the hash and use =~ in something like:

```
 hash.each do |k,v|    
   unless (k=~whatever.to_s).nil?
     puts v   
   end
 end
```

or change the Hash class to try =~ in addition to the normal matching conditions. (I think that last option would be difficult, in mri the Hash class seems to have a lot of C code)

Answer (score 13):

Are you looking for this behaviour?

```
myhash = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = 'hello' if k =~ /(\d+)/}

p myhash['aaa'] #=> nil
p myhash #=> {}
p myhash['1234'] #=>" hello"
p myhash #=> {"1234"=>"hello"}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can put Jean's answer in a default_proc

```
MAP = {
  /1/ => "one",
  /2/ => "two",
  /\d/ => "number"
}

MAP.default_proc = lambda do |hash, lookup|
  hash.each_pair do |key, value|
    return value if key =~ lookup
  end
  return nil
end

p MAP["2"] #=> "two"
p MAP[44] #=> "number"
```

Comment: This answer seems more versatile than the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

It never occurred to me to use a regex as a hash key. I'm honestly not sure if that should work, nor exactly how it would work if it should.

In any case, two thoughts:

1. In your attempts to lookup the item, you use `hash`, but the hash is named `myhash`.
2. If I play around with it, I get these results:

   ```
   hektor ~ ❯❯ irb
   >> myhash = {/(\d+)/ => "hello"}
   => {/(\d+)/=>"hello"} 
   >> myhash['2222']
   => nil 
   >> myhash[2222]
   => nil 
   >> myhash[/(\d+)/]
   => "hello"
   ```

This is using Ruby 1.9.2-p180.

Ok, checked and here's what works:

```
myhash = {/foo/ => "hello"}
myhash[/foo/] # => "hello"
```

The lookup is on *the key*, and the key is a regex, not one of the many potential matches of that regex.

Comment: @Telemachus - yeap myhash & hash was my typo. And it looks like ruby doesn't really treat /(\d+)/ as a regex at all.

Comment: @Telemachus - i came across this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082457/ruby-gsub-problem-when-using-backreference-and-hashes. And it looks like it should work.

Comment: the post you link to requires an iterator and a call to gsub which will interpret the regexp. In your case you are trying to cmpare a regex object with an Integer and a String respectively ...

Comment: @Jean - now I can see it too.

Comment: It does not work for me. "ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]" `irb(main):002:0> myhash[/222/]
=> nil`

Comment: @Jonas That's the point. You can't get it to lookup by match (at least not directly). The key is not a match, it's *the regex itself*. So try `myhash[/\d+/]` (for example), and it should return `"hello"` (or whatever you stored there.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a gem called Hashie that provides this feature (and much more): https://github.com/intridea/hashie#rash

It provides a data structure called Rash (short for regex-hash) that can be used like this

```
myhash = {/(\d+)/ => "hello"}
rash = Hashie::Rash.new(myhash)

>> rash["2222"]
=> "hello"
```

It really tries to match the key against the regexes so numeric keys won't work unless you convert them to string, which you can do easily by inheriting Rash into your own class