# Must a gsub hash key be a string, not a regexp?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to do a sequence of `gsub`s against one string, so I utilized the fact that `gsub` can take a hash as the second argument. One thing I wanted to do with `gsub` is to convert a sequence of one or more space/tab into a single space, so I have something essentially as follows:

```
gsub(/[ \t]+/, {/[ \t]+/ => ' '})
```

In my actual code, the first argument is a union of the regexp I gave here, and the second argument includes more key-value pairs.

Now, when I apply this to a string, all of the space/tabs are deleted. I suppose this is because the match to the first argument is not regarded as matching to the key `[ \t]` in the second argument (hash). Does the match in the second argument hash only looks for exact string match, not regexp match? If so, is there any way to get around it?

Comment: If what you want is to replace more than 2 or more spaces and/or tabs to one space, you could do something like `yourstring.gsub(/\s{2,}/,' ')`, or am I missing something?

Comment: That matches sequences including "\n" as well. I don't want to do that, although I can use `{2,}`.

Comment: @lal00 Also, your regexp will miss a single tab (as well as a single return).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311077/ruby-1-9-regex-as-a-hash-key). If you need to use the hash because many things have to be substituted, this might work:

```
list = Hash.new{|h,k|if  /\s+/ =~ k then ' ' else k end}
list['foo'] = 'bar'
list['apple'] = 'banana'

p "appleabc\t  \tabc  apple foo".gsub(/\w+|\W+/,list)
#=> "appleabc abc banana bar"
p list
#=>{"foo"=>"bar", "apple"=>"banana"} no garbage
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. Your suggestion seems close to what I want, and I think this is the track that I am forwarding to, but I need to think a little bit. Your answer might turn out to be the accepted answer, but still pending. One (possibly minor) concern is, an extra garbage key-value pair is created inside the hash every time it matches a different string.

Comment: There's no garbage in this case (post updated). Splitting the operation in two steps (removing the whitespace and replacing other items) looks like a reasonable alternative.

Comment: I see. I had misunderstood how the default value in a hash works. Now, your answer looks completely fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, `gsub` with a hash as the second parameter only matches against literal strings:

```
'hello'.gsub(/[eo]/, 'e' => 3, 'o' => '*')    #=> "h3ll*"
```

If you want to supply multiple hashes you could work around it by creating a hash, where the key/value pairs are the search => replacement pairs, iterate over the hash, and pass those into the gsub. Because Ruby 1.9+ maintains the insertion order of the hash, you're guaranteed that the search will occur in the order you want.

```
search_hash = {
  '1' => 'one', 
  'too' => 'two', 
  /[\t ]+/ => ' '
}
str = "1, too,\t3 ,    four"
search_hash.each { |n,v| str.gsub!(n, v) }
str #=> "one, two, 3 , four"
```

Comment: You gave me a clear answer to the title of my question, thanks. I had some equivalent of your code in mine, but it applies `gsub` as many times as the length of the `search_hash`, and it slows down proportional to the size of the `search_hash`. Then I realized that the second argument of gsub can take a hash, and when I gave a union of all the keys of `search_hash`, I needed to run `gsub` only once, and it seems faster, even though the union regexp is quite huge.

Comment: @sawa, Using Regex#union is one way to go about it, though the resulting regex will not be optimized. It's basically a bunch of patterns with `|` between them. Ruby doesn't have the equivalent of Perl's Regex::Assemble, which is fairly smart and returns a compact pattern.

Comment: Wish there were something like for Ruby.

Comment: @sawa "Wish there were something like for Ruby.". Yes, me too. The Perl code is very tightly coupled to Perl's way of doing things and makes my head spin - and I write a good amount of Perl. I suspect Ruby could do it more simply but we'd need a Oniguruma wizard who understands its internals.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the spaces/tabs replaced with one space, why not just specify that as the replacement, and omit the whole hash?

```
gsub(/[ \t]+/, ' ')
```

UPDATE: based on your comment, you can use the block syntax of gsub

```
gsub(/[ \t]+/) {|match| *do stuff here* }
```

Comment: Because it is not just a single pair of match-replacement that I want to apply, and I found out that doing a single `gsub` with hash is much faster than having a chain of multiple `gsub`s.

Comment: See my updated post. You can use the block syntax, pass in the match as a parameter and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: That's not what I want. steenslag's answer is close to what I want.