# Regex can this be achieved

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-negation

I'm too ambitious or is there a way do this

`to add a string` **if not present ?**

and

`remove a the same string` **if present?**

Do all of this using Regex and avoid the if else statement

Here an example

I have string

`"admin,artist,location_manager,event_manager"`

so can the substring **location_manager** be added or removed with regards to above conditions

basically I'm looking to **avoid the if else statement** and do all of this plainly in regex

`"admin,artist,location_manager,event_manager".test(/some_regex/)`

The  some_regex will remove **location_manager** from the string if present else it will add it

Am I over over ambitions

Comment: Is there a particular reason it has to be regex-only, or avoiding the use of 'else'? Is it just an academic question, or is there a particular practical application you're looking for? (i.e., would other language features other than regex also fit the bill?)

Comment: @YenTheFirst The reason I want I try to write ensure code cleanliness by avoid unnecesary if .. else .. clause to detect whether string contain the desired string or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use some sort of logic.

```
str += ',location_manager' unless str.gsub!(/location_manager,/,'')
```

I'm assuming that if it's not present you append it to the end of the string

Comment: That exactly how I have achieve but I was looking to make it more clean hence was thinking is there a way to avoid the logical statement like `unless` and `if` and achieve the whole only using regex but looking at the response I guess you can't .

Answer (score 1):

Regex will not actually add or remove anything in any language that I am aware of.  It is simply used to match.  You must use some other language construct (a regex based replacement function for example) to achieve this functionality. It would probably help to mention your specific language so as to get help from those users.

Comment: Ruby is my choice of language

Comment: `s/pattern/replacement/g` ? Or does that not count? (okay, not in ruby, so not _really_ relevant)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one kinda off-the-wall solution. It doesn't use regexes, but it also doesn't use any if/else statements either. It's more academic than production-worthy.

Assumptions: Your string is a comma-separated list of titles, and that these are a unique set (no duplicates), and that order doesn't matter:

```
titles = Set.new(str.split(','))
#=> #<Set: {"admin", "artist", "location_manager", "event_manager"}> 
titles_to_toggle = ["location_manager"]
#=> ["location_manager"]

titles ^= titles_to_toggle
#=> #<Set: {"admin", "artist", "event_manager"}>
titles ^= titles_to_toggle
#=> #<Set: {"location_manager", "admin", "artist", "event_manager"}>

titles.to_a.join(",")
#=> "location_manager,admin,artist,event_manager"
```

All this assumes that you're using a string as a kind of set. If so, you should probably just use a set. If not, and you actually need string-manipulation functions to operate on it, there's probably no way around except for using if-else, or a variant, such as the ternary operator, or `unless`, or Bergi's answer

Also worth noting regarding regex as a solution: Make sure you consider the edge cases. If 'location_manager' is in the middle of the string, will you remove the extraneous comma? Will you handle removing commas correctly if it's at the beginning or the end of the string? Will you correctly add commas when it's added? For these reasons treating a set as a set or array instead of a string makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

to remove something matching a pattern is really easy:

```
(admin,?|artist,?|location_manager,?|event_manager,?)
```

then choose the string to replace the match -in your case an empty string- and pass everything to the replace method.

The other operation you suggested was more difficult to achieve with regex only. Maybe someone knows a better answer

Comment: It wont avoid the if else statment I'm aware of this all I want is add or remove plain thru regex and the if else statement testing

Comment: but it's difficult to involve regex in that case without being overkill. Because if you need negative matching you have to specify n patterns one for each group you are looking for and you don't find. For each one of them you will then replace with the corresponding string. But it's not a nice solution. That's why a much better approach would be to keep a list in a structured way. Then for the first task just build the pattern I used above to replace unwanted terms with empty strings. In the second task just search for each item and if not matched append ",termnotfound" to the string

Comment: Please don't refer people to W3Schools.  It's a notorious source of inaccurate information and shallow, misleading explanations ([ref](http://w3fools.com/)).  For regexes, [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) is a much better place to start).

Comment: The OP was requesting a Ruby response.

Comment: ok good to know..apologize (and edited the message to remove bad references considering my answer was misleading anyway. sorry)

Answer (score 0):

No. Regex can only match/test whether "a string" is present (or not). Then, the function you've used can do something based on that result, for example `replace` can remove a match.

Yet, you want to do two actions (each can be done with regex), remove if present and add if not. You can't execute them sequentially, because they overlap - you need to execute either the one or the other. This is where if-else structures (or ternary operators) come into play, and they are required if there is no library/native function that contains them to do exactly this job. I doubt there is one in Ruby.

If you want to avoid the if-else-statement (for one-liners or expressions), you can use the ternary operator. Or, you can [use a labda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082457/ruby-gsub-problem-when-using-backreference-and-hashes) returning the correct value:

```
# kind of pseudo code
string.replace(/location,?|$/, function($0) return $0 ? "" : ",location" )
```

This matches the string "`location`" (with optional comma) or the string end, and replaces that with nothing if a match was found or the string "`,location`" otherwise. I'm sure you can adapt this to Ruby.